# fsck - correcting the inconsistency

Tags: linux-kernel, filesystems, fsck

I have a confusion regarding the `fsck` correction. I have corrupted an `ACL` block of an `inode`. Trying to understand how `fsck` corrects. What value does it compares and performs the correction.
     Does `fsck` corrects the inconsistency of the file system by comparing the `on-disk` structures with the `Journal` or with the buffer. Or does it checks the `superblocks` with the other structures.

Comment: Which filesystem do you have in mind? The process is very different on FAT as opposed to ZFS, for example.

Comment: The function which handles ACL/EA corruption diagnostics: http://code.metager.de/source/xref/linux/utils/e2fsprogs/e2fsck/pass1.c#1602

Answer (score 1):

"Correction" does not necessarily mean what you think it means.

Typically, there are *not* multiple copies of data or metadata on the disk, and even if there were, it might not be possible to determine which one is the correct one.

`fsck` merely changes the metadata so that the file system is *consistent* again.
But the result might be an outdated copy, or some garbage that looked like correct data; in extreme cases, the only way to make the corrupted data consistent might be to delete it altogether.